# How to exit LispWorks REPL debugger, returning to top level typing just a number, like SBCL?

Tags: debugging, common-lisp, read-eval-print-loop, abort, lispworks

I am currently using LispWorks, and I would like to setup the REPL so that I can exit the debugger simply by typing the number corresponding to `(abort) Return to top loop level 0`, the same way one can do using SBCL.

Normally, using LispWorks one needs to type `:c + [abort option number]`.

See a trivial example, using LispWorks:

```
CL-USER 1 > a

Error: The variable A is unbound.
  1 (continue) Try evaluating A again.
  2 Return the value of :A instead.
  3 Specify a value to use this time instead of evaluating A.
  4 Specify a value to set A to.
  5 (abort) Return to top loop level 0.

Type :b for backtrace or :c <option number> to proceed.
Type :bug-form "<subject>" for a bug report template or :? for other options.

CL-USER 2 : 1 > :c 5

CL-USER 3 >
```

While using SBCL, just the number will suffice:

```
* a

debugger invoked on a UNBOUND-VARIABLE in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {10012E0613}>:
  The variable A is unbound.

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:EXIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [CONTINUE   ] Retry using A.
  1: [USE-VALUE  ] Use specified value.
  2: [STORE-VALUE] Set specified value and use it.
  3: [ABORT      ] Exit debugger, returning to top level.

(SB-INT:SIMPLE-EVAL-IN-LEXENV A #<NULL-LEXENV>)
0] 3

*
```

The [REPL debugger commands documentation](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw71/LW/html/lw-18.htm) does not seem to list such possibility.

If possible, how can one exit LispWorks REPL debugger, returning to top level typing just a number, like with SBCL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you can't. It's also more consistent:

```
* a

debugger invoked on a UNBOUND-VARIABLE in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {10005004F3}>:
  The variable A is unbound.

    Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:EXIT) to exit from SBCL.

    restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
      0: [CONTINUE   ] Retry using A.
      1: [USE-VALUE  ] Use specified value.
      2: [STORE-VALUE] Set specified value and use it.
      3: [ABORT      ] Exit debugger, returning to top level.

    (SB-INT:SIMPLE-EVAL-IN-LEXENV A #<NULL-LEXENV>)
    0] 4

    4
    0] 3
    *
```

In the above example with SBCL, the numbers 0...3 choose that debugger option and all other numbers evaluate... that's a bit strange.

**LispWorks: simple abort in the debugger**

In LispWorks if you would want to use the `abort` restart, use `:a`:

```
CL-USER 1 > a

Error: The variable A is unbound.
  1 (continue) Try evaluating A again.
  2 Return the value of :A instead.
  3 Specify a value to use this time instead of evaluating A.
  4 Specify a value to set A to.
  5 (abort) Return to level 0.
  6 Return to top-level loop.
  7 Return from multiprocessing.

Type :b for backtrace or :c <option number> to proceed.
Type :bug-form "<subject>" for a bug report template or :? for other options.

CL-USER 2 : 1 > :a

CL-USER 3 >
```

There is also the <kbd>meta-shift-a</kbd> keyboard command in the LispWorks environment to abort in the debugger. Additionally the restarts are available in the menu and in the right-click context menu. Also one can use the abort icon in the icon bar of the listener/debugger/...

Advantage: you don't have to remember the number of the restart, since that may be different from error to error.

Comment: Thank you, that is the functionality I was looking for. As usual, LispWorks care in details is greatly satifying. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What you see in LispWorks' REPL when an error occur is generated by the [error](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/f_error.htm) function, as implemented by Lispworks. To change the way options are handled you would have to modify that function, something for which you don't have the documentation since it interacts with LispWorks' REPL in a particular way. So, in short, you can't. (BTW, the 'c' in :c stands for 'continue'.)

Comment: Its documentation on CLHS looks very similar, in its output, to what's in the current LispWorks' REPL.

Comment: a) the error display is entirely implementation dependent, and b) error just SIGNALs that error. Handling of errors, reporting of errors, displaying of restarts, etc. is done by other functions - in this case it is part of the functionality of a debugger.

Comment: Agreed. I used the word 'generated' about the output... So, yes, the display is ultimately the job of the debugger.

Comment: Now the question would be if the user can customize the debugger, by adding new commands. I don't know. But I would guess that it won't support using numbers as debugger commands.

Comment: I doesn't seem so: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lcl50/clwug/clw-198.html#HEADING198-0

Comment: no, that's something else for the backtrace display. The documentation is also not for LispWorks, but the old and discontinued Liquid CL (a Lisp implementation acquired by the company many years ago and only maintained for some customers who might be still using it...).